# Resize (Zoom in and Zoom out) in Compact Framework (C#)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, resize, bitmap

How I can zoom in a bitmap on Compact Framework? I read this article and http://geeks.netindonesia.net/blogs/clawford/archive/2008/04/20/resizing-bitmap-tutorial-in-net-cf.aspx and it's only to make the bitmap smaller.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Imaging APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452250.aspx) can be used for resizing.  Typically they are used for getting a thumbnail (making the image smaller) but there's nothing that says it has to.  It simply provides a "[CreateBitmapFromImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452205.aspx)" method, so you can always make the image larger.

For a reasonable [managed wrapper of the APIs](http://opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/5c29d99f-92fd-730a-ae57-c5b00e655a32.htm), see the [Smart Device Framework](http://www.smartdeviceframework.com).